# Selenium ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: java, selenium, web, click, element

I'm trying to automate certifications online but it is preventing me from clicking on a link to proceed to the form page.
I've used the other solutions given by others and went from not able to finding the element to getting org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:

Here's a snippet of my code

```
List<WebElement> linkList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(int i = 0; i < linkList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    if(linkList.get(i).getAttribute(("href")).contains("student")){
        linkList.get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Basically I used the loop to find which tagName contained the link I needed, but here's the error:

```
Jul 11, 2017 7:49:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-35FGBMU', ip: '192.168.1.117', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\pizza\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.Heg8gMUCnERq, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=54.0.1, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=7448.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: 322f496f-033f-4ccf-a0ab-324182e773b3

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:82)
    at com.Certify.startCertify(Certify.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I've also never seen anyone with ElementNotInteractableException, but a similar variant of it that is similar (I think) 
"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<li class="list label"
    <a href="/desW/cp/search/searchLocation.do?method=view&amp;launchFrom=fromStudentAdminMenu&amp;clearSearchCriteria=true&amp;mainMenuOption=prompt.menu.student.manage&amp;mainMenuOptionUrl=url.menu.manage.my.student" title="Manage My Students">Manage My Students</a>
</li>
```

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: Found a way to go around it by using

```
driver.navigate().to(String.valueOf(linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href")));
```

But would really like to know how to do it properly as I don't think this is the way.

Comment: I'm curious why did you click on a hyperlink and then you try to get `href` of another hyperlink. In my opinion, it's is impossible to do that because Selenium will navigate to the new URL and DOM will be cleared. Does the `a` that you've clicked navigate to a new URL?

Comment: @Buaban Not 100% sure what you mean. The code snippet is basically just looking for all the <a> tags and then finding the <href> that contains the text "student" and then I wish to click on the link.

linkList.get(3).click(); Was the result from the loop (Just found the index of the link I wanted). Sorry I guess it does look confusing from here

Comment: As @Buaban mentioned, you are trying to click the element `linkList.get(3)` which is of type `tagName a`. This should have redirected you to some other section/page. Hence, next when you call `linkList.get(i).click();` Selenium complains of **`ElementNotInteractableException` which `Indicates that a command could not be completed because the element is not pointer or keyboard interactable.`**

Comment: @DebanjanB the thing is, it doesn't actually goto the link for me on the browser. I just checked as well removing the linkList.get(3).click(); . It's giving me the same error

Comment: Okay, now that makes pretty much sense to me :) Can you consider providing us the relevant HTML DOM please?

Comment: Instead of getting all the "a" tags and iterate through each to find the exact one, we can write the the unique locator for that exact one element alone. DOM will be more helpful to help you further.

Comment: @JustinLi Does it throw error at statement `System.out.println(linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href"));` in the first loop (i=0)?

Comment: @buaban no it actually shows the correct link. but then it crashes with the error I posted when try to add .click()

Comment: @DebanjanB I'll add it to my question above

Comment: @santhoshkumar I did that at first, but I read somewhere that the error could be caused by hidden html tags with same attributes, so I am only using to looks to discover what other links there are in the same page

Answer (score 0):

Assumption 1: There are some hidden links. You have to skip them by checking `isDisplayed()`.

```
List<WebElement> linkList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(int i = 0; i < linkList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    if(linkList.get(i).getAttribute(("href")).contains("student") && linkList.get(i).isDisplayed()){
        linkList.get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Assumption 2: Some elements are being render on top of some links. You have to wait until they are clickable.

```
List<WebElement> linkList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(int i = 0; i < linkList.size(); i++){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    System.out.println(linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    if(linkList.get(i).getAttribute(("href")).contains("student")){
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(linkList.get(i));
            linkList.get(i).click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to click on " + linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href") + ". Exception: " + e.printStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```